# Font awesome in xpages doesn't work

Tags: xpages, font-awesome

I'm trying to use awesome font in a xpages application, following the [article](http://www.xpagetips.com/2013/08/five-minutes-to-font-awesome-icons.html) , however the images of the icons are not loading. Investigating from the debug (F12) of IE I noticed there is an error trying to load, as illustrated below. If you load that same local page it loads normally, as shown in the second screen of the IE debugger.

[image: Erro when loading in domino server]

[image: Sucessfull when loading local]

I have tried to change the url path of the font-aewsome.css file, it even loads the file that was giving error (according screen below), but the icons do not load. I am using version 3.2.1. Could it be that?

[image: changing url path]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact the cause of the problem were two factors:

The conflict of the awesome font files with the theme of the application. This problem is resolved, according to articles ([article 1](https://quintessens.wordpress.com/page/10/?lang=en) and [article 2](https://quintessens.wordpress.com/2015/10/06/runtime-optimized-resources-in-conjunction-with-font-awesome/)), by separating the source face of the ccs file into another file and making an external reference to that last css file..

IE Compatibility Mode: The application was running locally because the compatibility mode was in Edge. On the server Domino server was in the compatibility mode of version 7.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at this article : https://xcellerant.net/2014/04/07/implementing-font-awesome-4-0-3-in-xpages/

This is for a newer version but the just is XPages/Domino does not like "?v=4.0.3" in the source files.

```
src: url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.0.3');
```

should be :

```
src: url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot');
```

You would need to do that for every instance.

Comment: I already read this article, but I copied the awesome files from the article quoted in the problem description. In the related file, those references have been removed, so I guess that's not the problem.